# Learning to program without a language?

Tags: computer-science

From my experience there are many similar commands amongst several different languages that express the same situation. (i.e. the for loop, similar data structures)

So is there a way to learn pure programming techniques, such as the thought processes and general conceptual framework associated with programming before even dealing with a computer language?

I feel as if when people teach programming they lose a lot of people by skipping the logic necessary to move forward. Sadly I am in this group.

Comment: Although I like your question, it isn't suited for SO. Maybe you have more luck in http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I feel that it is a process that is better learned by doing, especially if you want to get the thought process down.

Comment: While there are probably some exercises which one *might hope* guide the mind in the right direction for later programming or CS education, you can't really write programs without something to write programs in, i.e. a programming language. Likewise, you can't talk about computation without having some notion of computation.

Comment: Classic logic is where I would start if I had to do it over but I think most good programmers don't realize the level of intuition that they are using to learn.

Comment: There are various pseudo-languages (mostly Algol-like) that are sometimes used for instruction.  And it's not unusual, in some schools, to begin with something like Smalltalk that is perceived as "cleaner" or "more complete" or even "more limited" than Java or C.  But pretty quickly you have to do real stuff and face the ugliness of real languages.  (I still say that all programmers should be started on FORTRAN IV.  If it was good enough for me it's good enough for them.)

Comment: It seems that the hardest thing for many would-be programmers to grasp is the difference between "a thing" and "a pointer to a thing".  To grasp that you probably need a "real" (and pointer-based) language.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  When it comes to coding, the best way to learn is by doing.  Learning from your mistake will be the best thing you can do, but that doesn't mean don't seek out help.

You can teach yourself with some books.  But when it comes down to it this is not a read the book and pass the test with an A type thing.  This is developing certain methods that will work for you and the environment and the only way to learn is by doing.

Answer (score 0):

How about learning programming concepts with a graphical environment? I would say [Alice](http://www.alice.org/) is the answer.

From the website:

> Using an innovative programming environment to support the creation of
>   3D animations, the Alice Project provides tools and materials for
>   teaching and learning computational thinking, problem solving, and
>   computer programming across a spectrum of ages and grade levels.

Answer (score 0):

Since *Programming* involves writing instructions for a computer, I'm not sure it would make sense to learn programming without learning a language.

If you want to study the underlying theories without getting too stuck in implementation, you could study *Computer Science* and look into automata theory and data structures and algorithm analysis and other subjects which don't bind you to any specific language.

Comment: While the CS subjects you mention are very useful for programmers (as in, people who use programming languages), they broadly fall into one of two groups: (1) Language-agnostic, but require choosing a language to use in any way. (2) Language-agnostic because they are very disconnected from any sort of programming, more concerned with *models of* computation rather than actual computation.